# Is there a way to automatically escape backslashes when copy/pasting in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, escaping

I'm looking for a feature or extension similar to the one present in `IntelliJ` that escapes backslashes automatically while copy/pasting windows paths into the code. Are there any ?

Answer (score 4):

If you are pasting paths into strings in C# code then the language provides a string style where backslashes do not need escaping. Just prefix the string with an `@` character. These two strings are the same:

```
string aaa = @"C:\some\path\to\a.file";
string bbb = "C:\\some\\path\\to\\a.file";
```

Comment: This doesn't help for strings containing double-quote characters, of course.

Answer (score 4):

ReSharper does it seamlessly but of course, it costs money.

There's also a free VS extension that does that, here:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=martinw.SmartPaster2013